# What are some good gaming strategies for slither.io?

Tags: slither.io

Slither.io belongs to my favourite browser games, even though I'm not a very good player of it. I tend to get eaten just when I get more mass and it's getting annoying for me, getting after 1/2 hours getting killed with 5000+ mass.

**What's a good strategy to gain mass fast and then surviving for some time while big?** That is, getting mass fast and not getting orbizized (killed)? ***All answers will be apreciated.***

Comment: This seems like it would be awful broad.  It would depend greatly on other players, their playstyle, and your current situation.  I don't think there's ever one strategy that beats all others all the time.

Comment: @Frank It's also primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @Peanut I checked the off-topic flagging reasons; Questions about best strategies are NOT off-topic :-)

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek Asking for best tends to be rather subjective, even if the question topic itself isn't off-topic.  What you ask is still subject to the guidelines and rules inherent in the SE network, and Arqade in particular.

Comment: Dude. It's open. Give it a rest.

Comment: You're using faulty reasoning as justification to keep your question open.  That's not how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slither.io is largely a game based on risk and reward. You constantly ask yourself: what is the risk if I do this and what is the potential reward I get?

A few general rules:

- Look at the minimap in the bottom right corner. You see your current position, and the general position of all other snakes. Most snakes are in the middle. There is more to gain there, especially for a smaller snake, but it might get crowded.
- Remember that blocking a larger snake while being small has a much larger reward than trying to kill a smaller snake while being large. Unless you are confident that you can circle a snake, or a couple of snakes, and get a decent amount of mass out if it, don't take the risk.
- Remember that as the larger snake, you have trouble turning. You can cross over yourself, so if you get surrounded, just claim a large-ish amount of space and stay in that place for a bit. Always turn towards your snake if in doubt what to do, as you are more likely to survive that.
- As a larger snake, don't speed much to collect bubbles. Of course, using speed you can collect more of them, collecting more mass, but as a larger snake you are less agile. You are more likely to end up dieing by bumping into a snake that came speeding from the other side. When going a normal pace you have all the time in the world to turn.
- Remember that the easiest way to kill other snakes is by surprising them. If a strategy didn't work out, don't try that strategy again on that snake. It won't work, and people will quickly adapt and kill you instead as they figure out what your next move will be.
- If smaller snakes bother you, don't feel discouraged to boost for a short period to get clear of those smaller snakes. Keep smaller snakes at least 2 of their lengths behind the head of your snake. If smaller snakes are persistent, remember that you can always block their path by going very close to an other snake, then going in a direction that is now blocked off.
- When surrounding other snakes, keep a large area occupied. You kill an other snake by making a few turns, then let the edges of your snake creep inward. If you circle around a lot on a small area, even much smaller snakes than you can surround you, causing all kinds of problems for you. If you see that an other snake might be trying to surround you, abandon your prey. It is not worth the risk.

---

Some other tips and tricks:

- Don't play on wifi if you can help it. A better connection to the server has all kinds of advantages.
- As a small snake you don't have much to loose. It could be a valid strategy to just restart if you can't get an significant amount of mass in a short time to get started. In other words: Take a lot of risk as a small snake, and don't worry about potentially loosing it. There was only a small time investment made, and you would likely spend a lot more time trying to gain the same amount of mass the safe way.

Comment: A strategy I found out:

     1. Go towards the middle of the map and find a big snake
     2. Follow the big snake's tail until it dies
     3. Take the orbs left
     4. Go towards the less crowded map edge
     5.  Play freely